# Laravel 5.7 redirects me to install and system requirements

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.7

I am setting up existing laravel project, Now when I start by providing localhost/projectname/public,

instead it redrects me to `localhost/install`. 
I have try to look into public/.htaccess file it says this:
I have changed it to local as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything needs to be changed or updated if I dnt want to run via Php artisan?

Comment: Seems unlikely Laravel is causing the redirect. Are you able to load other php files ok?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand what's your question about. You posted the laravel default .htaccess, and there is no `install` directory or route in a default laravel project.

Comment: You mention you are looking for a way to run the web application using something besides `path artisan` (I assume you mean `php artisan serve`). Have you tried setting up a Virtual Host in Apache?